# Split a large MySQL dump per database

Tags: mysql, backup

I have a large MySQL data backup file which consists all the databases. But I want to restore only a few number of databases from above.

Is there a good way to split the sql file into several files per database?

Comment: without splitting  you can restore specific database using this command mysql - u root -p --one-database databas_name <file.sql

Comment: At the moment mysql server is crashed and this is the only dump available. I want to restore some of the databases in a different server now.

Comment: first create the database . then apply this command with correct database name . follow the steps for each database .

Comment: I posted it as answer  if it's useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @thanuja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without splitting you can restore specific database using this command

```
 mysql -u root -p --one-database database_name < main-db-dump.sql
```

First create the database. Then apply this command with correct `database_name`. Follow the steps for each database.